# tell excel to treat hex values as text

Tags: excel, hex

I have a large hex file i've imported into excel as a csv. So its not really a hex file, just hex strings in a csv format. I have told excel to treat the values as text and they are left justified as I would expect but when I replace all the "0x" chars with '' it changes 0x0000 to 0 (still left justified). Not a huge issue but it's still not treating it as text. The real problem is what it does with "0x18E3", it treats it as scientific notation and I get 1.80E+04 and its right justified. Its change my cell format from text to scientific.

Comment: Replace the `0x` with a single quote `'`. This tells Excel to format the data as text and preserves formatting.